# Unable to obtain lock on store lock file

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm building a project with embedded Neo4j and Spring Data, and i'm having problems with file lock, i'm getting the exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
    ... 47 more
```

There is no other processes using the data/graph.db, and it's not a permission problem, the data folder is created during runtime, and i already tried change the permissions to 777.

my applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="br.com.teste.repository" />
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="br.com.teste.model"/>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
            destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg value="data/graph.db"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServer"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
    </bean>
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Data Neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- Apache Commons Lang -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSON Resolver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
```

Why i'm still getting the exception of Unable to obtain lock?

**Edit:**
I was having so much problems trying to config the embedded database, so i tried the REST wich was so much easier to config, and is fully working now.

Comment: You say there is no other processes using the data/graph.db.   Have you verified this (i.e. by using the lsof utility)?  Or are you just saying you're not aware of any other processes running that would be using it?   What does lsof | grep graph.db return?

Comment: For what it's worth, looking through the code that throws that exception; it's quite straightforward: either something has that file open, or it's not writeable. If you create the directory at runtime, I accept that it's probably writeable. Which means you need to double/triple/quadrupel check there's not some other process already open that has that file/dir open.

Comment: On a dirty shutdown there is a lock file that can get left behind, even when the store is no longer used by any process. The exception thrown in that case looks a lot like this.

Comment: try make copy of this directory and try again

Comment: running `lsof` might help to identify which processes still have a lock on the datastore files

Comment: You have to make sure to `close()` your application context, otherwise the database is not shut down correctly.

Comment: I had a similar issue and the problem was I was running the Neo4j version in the browser from the terminal at the same time that I was trying to access it from my java code and this was causing the error. The solution was to stop the Neo4j from the command line and execute the code and then relaunch the Neo4j from the command line which solved the issue.
The video link helped "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g-vCsZO_3g"