# datanucleus neo4j - Unable to obtain lock on store lock file

Tags: jpa, neo4j, datanucleus

I am developing an WebApp that uses datanucleus as JPA - Provider and Neo4j as No-SQL database.

My dependencies are

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>[1.2, 1.3)</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My persistence.xml looks like

```
<persistence-unit name="neo4j">
 <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
 <class>entities.Person</class>
 <class>entities.Car</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="neo4j:C:\Users\phe\Documents\Neo4j\sampledatanucleus"/>
        <!-- <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="neo4j"/> -->
        <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="neo4j"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am persisting the entities like this

```
        Person person = new Person(personName, personAge);
        Car car = new Car(carName);
        car.setOwner(person);
        person.getCars().add(car);
        em.persist(person);
```

When persisting the entities I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: C:\Users\phe\Documents\Neo4j\sampledatanucleus\store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:93)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:85)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:528)
... 153 more
```

This makes me crazy. The directory I defined in the perstistence.xml is empty when I start the applictaion. Therefore it is impossible that it is locked by another process. DataNucleus then creates the database. I can access it with Neo4j Browser. But Persisting does not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This is the class I use for querying

```
@Stateless
public class Manager {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "neo4j")
  private EntityManager em;

  public List<Person> queryCache() {
    String statement = "Select o from Person o";
    Query query = em.createQuery(statement, Person.class);
    List<Person> list = query.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return list;
  }

  public void save(String personName, Double personAge, String carName) {

    Person person = new Person(personName, personAge);
    Car car = new Car(carName);
    car.setOwner(person);
    person.getCars().add(car);
    em.persist(person);
  }
}
```

These two methods get called by the controller when clicking the corresponding buttons on the view.

Comment: When I use their JPA Tutorial sample (downloadable) and simply enable Neo4j in the pom.xml and persistence.xml it works out of the box. Perhaps you've misconfigured something?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694563/unable-to-obtain-lock-on-store-lock-file comments

Comment: And http://www.schakko.de/2016/03/23/fixing-unable-to-obtain-lock-on-store-lock-file-when-using-the-embedded-database-of-neo4j/

Comment: Are there other configurations than the persistence.xml and the pom.xml? I can not think of other configurations that might be misconfigured.
@Neil Stockton I cannot adapt your solution to my problem since in that example they use the neo4j Java driver. I am using DataNucleus. So I think this can not be compared.

Comment: DataNucleus USES THE Neo4j Java driver!!! It's in your pom.xml. It is where the issue lies

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I wanted to say something else. Of course DataNucleus uses the driver. But I do not use the driver's interface. So you think I should use  ((EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver()).close(); even though? But where should i place it?

Comment: Is it possible, that datanucleus with neo4j does not work within an application server like wildlfy?

Comment: I don't expect DataNucleus cares where it is used; it is a Java process after all. If you look in the code, it is simply using the Neo4j API so you can debug all calls https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-neo4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/neo4j/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L88

Comment: It should be mentioned that if you are trying to have multiple threads accessing this at the same time then you will likely get problems ... it has a GraphDatabaseService for each EM, and each will want the file. But you don't say what your code does.

Comment: I do not create explictly several threads.
What do you mean? I don't say what my code does?

Comment: you don't say whether you have a single thread (or request), with just that code. A normal web app has requests so each request represents a thread, and each request has an EM, which has a transaction and connection ... and hits the problem I said when you have multiple. The log tells you what is happening.

Comment: I have one class that acts as controller. Another Class executes the queries. In this class I have injected the entity manager via @PersistenceContext. Then I have two methods which use the entity manager, a write method and a read method. So I don't create multiple threads.

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see the class I use for querying.